# Spring deployment error

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must not be null
```

---

```
SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
```

Please help on this issue on my project working on Spring 4 , hibernate 4 , and apache tomcat 8.0.3.0

Updated the application context:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

     <!--scan the given package for repository--> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.persondata.dao"/> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.persondata.daoimpl"/> 

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
    </bean>

     <!--tx annotation driven scans registered spring beans for @Transactional-->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!--support for @Controller and @RequestMapping-->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <!--support for general annotations such as @Required, @Autowired, @PostConstruct, and so on.-->
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/persondata" /> 
                <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value=""/> 
        <property name="connection.characterEncoding" value = "utf-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.persondata.entity"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="c3p0.minPoolSize">15</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.maxPoolSize">1000</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.timeout">5000</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.max_statement">500</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

Thank you so much for your help. I resolved the issue , I gave wrong datasource properties(username and password).

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must not be null`   I see this error, your context did not start because you failed to provide some kind of URL to one of your bean. Please check. Also provide the application context file here for helping you out.

Comment: you should provide related codes so that people can help.

Comment: I resolved the issue , I gave wrong datasource properties(username and password). Thank you guys for your help.